# backbone.js All the templates are loading by default

Tags: javascript, performance, templates, backbone.js

My Project is almost similar to this [Backbone.js Sample Application](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/)

 
 But, My Application download all the templates by default
('text!templates/projects/list.html' ) . Is this correct ?

I am under the impression that until unless you invoke the 
specific item in the router navigation list, It won't load the views, collection and template files. Am I in same Page ?

For example, If I route "sample.com/users", It should load only collection and views associated with this "user" router specification. Correct me if I am wrong.

Raja K

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS works by defining the dependencies of all your modules.  Since `main.js` requires `app` before it does anything else, it will first load all the files that `app` depends on.  Since `app` requires in `router`, and `router` requires `ProjectListView`, and `ProjectListView` requires its text-based template, those files all get loaded *before* anything happens; RequireJS first makes sure every callback in a `define(...)` or `require(...)` function has what it needs.  This is as expected.

If you want to defer the loading of the files until the actual creation of the view, you would structure your View differently. It complicates things quite a bit, which is why most folks don't do it.

Below is one option working off of the `ProjectListView` from the sample app.  It uses [When JS](https://github.com/cujojs/when) to provide a Promise to handle the asynchronous loading of the template.  This has the unfortunate side-effect of making the `render` function asynchronous too, as it may need to wait for the template file to show up.  Still....

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'when'
], function($, _, Backbone, when){
    var ProjectListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#container'),

        initialize: function() {
            // Load the template file upon the creation of the view
            this._ensureTemplateLoaded();
        },

        // This returns a Promise that will be resolved after the
        // template file is loaded.
        _ensureTemplateLoaded: function() {
            var self = this;
            return when.promise(function(resolve) {
                // Require in the template.  Note that this is
                // a no-op if the template has been loaded previously
                require([
                    'text!templates/project/list.html'
                ], function(projectListTemplate) {
                    // Resolve our promise, providing the template
                    resolve(projectListTemplate);
                 });
             });
        },

        render: function(){
            // Wait for the promise to be resolved to make sure
            // we have loaded the template before attempting to render
            var self = this;
            this._ensureTemplateLoaded().then(function(projectListTemplate) {

                // Huzzah!  Now we can do the regular rendering with the
                // template provided by the Promise
                var data = {};
                var compiledTemplate = _.template( projectListTemplate, data );

                 // Append our compiled template to this Views "el"
                 self.$el.append( compiledTemplate );
             });
         }
  });

  // Our module now returns our view
  return ProjectListView;
});
```

As noted, it's a bit more complex.  The benefits to the end user are pretty minimal, unless you're loading a very large number of files.

Finally, note that RequireJS's optimizer, `r.js`, can be used to accomplish effectively the same thing by having it build multiple fully-assembled JS modules (i.e. the targeted module along with all its dependencies).  This typically means the client will download the same JS multiple times, however, so it also is only done to separate different components of large applications.

http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html.

Comment: Thanks. I have got one more suggestion to load the template through $.get , seems working.fine. [caching Templates](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/10/javascript-performance-pre-compiling-and-caching-html-templates/)